# Calling C DLL's compiled with SAFESEH set to no from Inno Script

Tags: inno-setup

I have an existing DLL that is working fine when being called from Inno Script however I need to add a function that calls another third party library (of which I do not have the source code).

Whenever I do that I get a 'could not call proc' error.

In order to compile (in Visual Studio) my DLL with the added function, I have to set SAFESEH to no because of the third party library.  Is this likely to be what stops Inno Script from working? Are there any options available to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: I can make a contrived example but ultimately the question is will a DLL compiled with SAFESEH turned off (set to no) work with inno?

Comment: Where that DLL contains a function call to a third party library that requires SAFESEH to be off.

Comment: The contrived example probably would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turning **off** SafeSEH is unlikely to prevent anyone from calling your function.

It is more likely that the 3rd-party library added a dependency to some DLL (MSVC run-time etc.). Use [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if your imported DLLs change after you add the 3rd-party library.